# Как кастомизировать вывод постов wordpess

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Кто знает как кастомизировать вывод постов. Напирмер вот таким.
Просто понимаете, мне не очень нравится дефолтный вывод постов. Какая-то уродская. Поэтому порекомендуйте пожалуйста плагинов для этого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Просто хочу кастомизировать отображение записей (постов).

Comment: Это "проблема" темы.  А с духом разговаривать  не нужно - это же бот.

Comment: простите я не знал) Можно спросить, а на каком фале нужно врестать посты? То есть те посты которые создаются в гутенбег.

Comment: Посты в редакторе и "верстаются". При необходимости можно поправить с помощью css. А для  расширения гутенберга другими блоками есть плагины. ЗЫ. Чтобы тут обратиться к человеку нужно написать его ник через @

Comment: @SeVlad Простите я тут новый. А можно ли изменить html код какого то виджета елементора. Например виджета **posts**. Если вы в курсе то знаете что этот виджет это целая форма. Нуу просто хочу ещё одну кнопку добавить. Простите меня, за то что так много задаю вопросы.

Comment: элементор.. Чур меня! Я знать его не хочу, но "изменить код" это точно не про него (и тебе советую выбросить эту гадость и никогда не подбирать). Но здесь не форум и комменты не предназначены для вопросов. Каждый вопрос нужно отдельно задавать.

Comment: @SeVlad мне тоже надоел этот елементор. Хочу переписать весь сайт вручную! То есть создать свою тему! Так проще. А то контейнеры задолбали!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал вывод постов вручную. Через php код.